# What are the benefits of using ldap with Samba?

Tags: ldap, samba, openldap

I am curious to know what are the benefits of using LDAP with Samba? In other words, without integrating LDAP with Samba, what are the limitations of Samba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without LDAP, each user would need to have a configuration of their SAMBA information configured on each machine they wished to use.

With LDAP the SAMBA details can be store in LDAP and managed for all users in one spot.

-jim

Comment: Not to mention that without LDAP you can't have backup domain controllers.